# regular expression for floating point value

Tags: jquery, regex, floating-point, alphanumeric

I want my textbox to have only floating point value, and filter out any symbols and alphabetical letters, the nearest solution i found is:

```
jQuery(".sow-items .discovery_repeat input.hours").live("keyup", function(e) {       
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\d]/, ''));       
});
```

but it also filters out decimal point. how to exclude decimal from the above filter or any new suggestions?

Comment: Rather than filter out things-that-aren't-floating point, how about making sure it *is* a valid floating point? You also need to state whether or not you'll allow exponential notation.

Comment: @DaveNewton no exponential notation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
jQuery(".sow-items .discovery_repeat input.hours").live("keyup", function(e) {       
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\d.]/g, ''));       
});
```

Comment: SHULDT it be `/[^\d\.]/` escaping the `.` ?

Comment: @DaveNewton your right it can cause multiple decimals to be included, can you suggest a better solution. thanks

Comment: The dot does not need to be escaped when used inside of a character class.

Answer (score 1):

`/\b[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+\b/g` or `/^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$/` should do the trick, unless you want to allow numbers like "1.4E-15" in there.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html has some suggestions for that unusual case.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(".sow-items .discovery_repeat input.hours").live("keyup", function(e) {   
    var newVal = $(this).val().replace(/[^\d.]/, '').split(".");
    if ( newVal.length>2 ) newVal.length = 2; newVal.join("."); 
    $(this).val(newVal);       
});
```

@Dave Newton: Only one `.` ..

Answer (score 0):

You need to match either non digit or non dot and the dot needs to be escaped

```
jQuery(".sow-items .discovery_repeat input.hours").live("keyup", function(e) {       
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\d]|[^\.]/, ''));       
});
```

Comment: Not when it's inside a character class.

Comment: True, the dot does not need to be escaped.