# Make input to get only numbers with two decimal places

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

Currently I am using following jQuery code to filter only digits:

```
$('#input_field').keyup(function(e) {
    if (/\D/g.test(this.value)) {
        this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
    }
});
```

But I want to get floating point numbers(upto to 2 decimal places) like this:

```
10.2
1.23
1000.10
```

Comment: not clear what you try to do :"to filters only digits" what exactly should your input look like?

Comment: The logic would be to split by the decimal place (after your current treatment) and truncate the second element and then join with a decimal point.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8658341/regular-expression-for-floating-point-value

Comment: I think you may require an [HTML5 pattern](http://html5pattern.com/), not a design-pattern.

Comment: @jsexpert: I have given input values at the end of question that I want to get. Above code is just an example that how I am getting only digits without dot. I want to change my code according to requirements.

Answer (score 11):

Try this regex:

```
/^\d+(\.\d{0,2})?$/
```

Your JS:

```
$('#input_field').keyup(function(e) {
    var regex = /^\d+(\.\d{0,2})?$/g;
    if (!regex.test(this.value)) {
        this.value = '';
    }
});
```

Comment: how to apply this using JS?

Comment: @AbingPj: There is an example using JS code below

Answer (score 3):

try

```
toFixed(2)
```

eg:

```
var number = 2.234239;
var numberfixed=number.toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to use typing interval, because keyup is to quick and the regex don't approve something like this `0.`

```
var typingTimer; 

var doneTypingInterval = 1000;
$('.myInputField').keyup(function(){
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    if ($('.myInputField').val) {
        typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
    }
});

function doneTyping () {
  var vale = $('.myInputField').val();
  var regexTest = /^\d+(?:\.\d\d?)?$/;
  var ok = regexTest.test(vale);
  if(!ok){
      $('.myInputField').val('');
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jWbsE/

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the regular expression used to test the values against.

```
/^\D+(\.\D\D?)?$/
```

This will allow numbers with no decimal point, or with a decimal point and one or two digits after.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dot = fVal.split(".");
    var len0 = 0;
    var len1 = 0;
    if (dot.length == 2) {

        len0 = dot[0].length;
        len1 = dot[1].length;
    } else if (dot.length > 2)
        len1 = 3;
    else
        len1 = 0;
    var fValFlt = parseFloat(fVal);
    var fValN = isNaN(fVal);

    if ((len1 > 2) || fValN == true || fValFlt < 0) {
        //failure arguments
    } else {
        //success arguments
    }
```

In above code *fVal* is the field value for which you might be checking for.